# A question of.. Probability!

Tags: probability, dice

You have six loaded dice (I mean falsified, non regular).

In the first die there is always a $10\%$ of probability for $1$ to come out.
In the second die there is always a $20\%$ of probability for $2$ to come out.
In the third die there is always a $30\%$ of probability for $3$ to come out.
In the fourth die there is always a $40\%$ of probability for $4$ to come out.
In the fifth die there is always a $50\%$ of probability for $5$ to come out.
In the sixth die there is always a $60\%$ of probability for $6$ to come out.

All six dice are 6 sided, and the remaining numbers of each dice have an equal probability to come out.

What is the probability for $21$ to come out?

Comment: What are the probabilities for the remaining numbers?  Equally distributed?

Comment: Oh I forgot. Yes they are equally distributed.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for the probability of the sum of all six dice to be equal to 21?

Comment: There are lots of ways in which you can get $21$. Anyway, yes: the total sum must be $21$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dr. Xorile gives a brute-force approach; here's a more efficient dynamic programming method.

Let $p_k(n)$ be the probability that the first $k$ dice sum to $n$.  The question then asks for $p_6(21)$

We can define $p$ recursively, starting with the base case $k=0$:

$$
p_0(n)=\delta_{0,n}
$$

($\delta_{ij}$ is the Kroneker delta, equal to $1$ when its arguments are the same, and $0$ when they differ.)

Next we need to know the probability distributions for the different dice.  The $k$th die has one face with probability $k/10$, and the others five have probability $(1-k/10)/5=1/5-k/50$.

Finally, we calculate $p$ for successive values of $k$:

$$
p_k(n) = \left[\sum_{i\in(1\ldots 6)}(1-\delta_{ki})(1/5-k/50)p_{k-1}(n-i)\right]+(k/10)\left[p_{k-1}(n-k)\right]
$$

Coding this in *Mathematica*:

```
p[0, 0] = 1;
p[0, _] = 0;
p[k_, n_] := p[k, n] =
    Sum[(1 - KroneckerDelta[i, k]) (1/5-k/50) p[k-1, n-i], {i, 1, 6}] + (k/10) p[k-1, n-k]

p[6, 21] (* 32890443/390625000 *)
```

This is the same result as Dr. Xorile, but achieved in $O(nkd)$ time vs. $O(d^k)$ (where $d$ is the number of faces per die).

Comment: Simply Beautiful!!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming equally distributed probability of the "other" throws:

> 6:  2.1504e-06
>    7:  1.516032e-05
>    8:  6.105599999999999e-05
>    9:  0.0001866496
>   10:  0.0004811571199999999
>   11:  0.0011080704000000004
>   12:  0.002317765120000012
>   13:  0.00445283840000005
>   14:  0.007932728320000082
>   15:  0.013234946560000219
>   16:  0.02078419456000026
>   17:  0.03073397760000035
>   18:  0.042942725119999754
>   19:  0.05675394815999913
>   20:  0.07107977727999641
>   **21:  0.08419953407999499**
>   22:  0.09412483327999363
>   23:  0.09939161855999414
>   24:  0.09888333311999539
>   25:  0.09254429439999612
>   26:  0.08094589695999811
>   27:  0.06610059775999934
>   28:  0.050275064320000035
>   29:  0.03517282560000011
>   30:  0.022496632320000085
>   31:  0.012905395200000015
>   32:  0.006652177920000004
>   33:  0.0029200895999999987
>   34:  0.0010063871999999997
>   35:  0.0002651443199999999
>   36:  2.9030399999999992e-05

Or, if you prefer the exact answer:

> 6:  21/9765625
>    7:  2961/195312500
>    8:  477/7812500
>    9:  7291/39062500
>   10:  23494/48828125
>   11:  10821/9765625
>   12:  905377/390625000
>   13:  173939/39062500
>   14:  1549361/195312500
>   15:  5169901/390625000
>   16:  4059413/195312500
>   17:  600273/19531250
>   18:  8387251/195312500
>   19:  22169511/390625000
>   20:  13882769/195312500
>   **21:  32890443/390625000**
>   22:  36767513/390625000
>   23:  38824851/390625000
>   24:  19313151/195312500
>   25:  7230023/78125000
>   26:  31619491/390625000
>   27:  12910273/195312500
>   28:  19638697/390625000
>   29:  2747877/78125000
>   30:  8787747/390625000
>   31:  504117/39062500
>   32:  2598507/390625000
>   33:  57033/19531250
>   34:  9828/9765625
>   35:  25893/97656250
>   36:  567/19531250

---

Here's a brief explanation of how I did this:
First, here's a list of the probabilities associated with the different dice throws:

> Dice 1 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 1/10
>   Probability of a 2 is 9/50
>   Probability of a 3 is 9/50
>   Probability of a 4 is 9/50
>   Probability of a 5 is 9/50
>   Probability of a 6 is 9/50
>
> ---
>
> Dice 2 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 4/25
>   Probability of a 2 is 1/5
>   Probability of a 3 is 4/25
>   Probability of a 4 is 4/25
>   Probability of a 5 is 4/25
>   Probability of a 6 is 4/25
>
> ---
>
> Dice 3 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 7/50
>   Probability of a 2 is 7/50
>   Probability of a 3 is 3/10
>   Probability of a 4 is 7/50
>   Probability of a 5 is 7/50
>   Probability of a 6 is 7/50
>
> ---
>
> Dice 4 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 3/25
>   Probability of a 2 is 3/25
>   Probability of a 3 is 3/25
>   Probability of a 4 is 2/5
>   Probability of a 5 is 3/25
>   Probability of a 6 is 3/25
>
> ---
>
> Dice 5 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 1/10
>   Probability of a 2 is 1/10
>   Probability of a 3 is 1/10
>   Probability of a 4 is 1/10
>   Probability of a 5 is 1/2
>   Probability of a 6 is 1/10
>
> ---
>
> Dice 6 probabilities
>   Probability of a 1 is 2/25
>   Probability of a 2 is 2/25
>   Probability of a 3 is 2/25
>   Probability of a 4 is 2/25
>   Probability of a 5 is 2/25
>   Probability of a 6 is 3/5

Then, there are only $6^6 = 46656$ possible throws.  This is a small number for a computer to iterate through, so I do so.  For each throw, I calculate what the probability of it occurring is, and what the sum of the dice is.  I accumulate that sum to the probability of getting that number.

Here are some examples of ways to throw 21:

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 1 (probability 7/50  )
Die 4 has a 6 (probability 3/25  )
Die 5 has a 6 (probability 1/10  )
Die 6 has a 6 (probability 3/5  )
Probability of this throw: 63/3906250

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 2 (probability 7/50  )
Die 4 has a 5 (probability 3/25  )
Die 5 has a 6 (probability 1/10  )
Die 6 has a 6 (probability 3/5  )
Probability of this throw: 63/3906250

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 2 (probability 7/50  )
Die 4 has a 6 (probability 3/25  )
Die 5 has a 5 (probability 1/2  )
Die 6 has a 6 (probability 3/5  )
Probability of this throw: 63/781250

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 2 (probability 7/50  )
Die 4 has a 6 (probability 3/25  )
Die 5 has a 6 (probability 1/10  )
Die 6 has a 5 (probability 2/25  )
Probability of this throw: 21/9765625

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 3 (probability 3/10  )
Die 4 has a 4 (probability 2/5  )
Die 5 has a 6 (probability 1/10  )
Die 6 has a 6 (probability 3/5  )
Probability of this throw: 9/78125

---

Die 1 has a 1 (probability 1/10  )
Die 2 has a 1 (probability 4/25  )
Die 3 has a 3 (probability 3/10  )
Die 4 has a 5 (probability 3/25  )
Die 5 has a 5 (probability 1/2  )
Die 6 has a 6 (probability 3/5  )
Probability of this throw: 27/156250

Obviously this goes on for some time, but in the end you get the answer.  Below is the python script:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import fractions

#Generate the probabilities for the dice
dice=defaultdict(list)
for die in range(1,7):
    for throw in range(7):
        if throw==0:
            dice[die].append(0)
        elif die==throw:
            dice[die].append(fractions.Fraction(die,10))
        else:
            dice[die].append(fractions.Fraction(10-die,50))

#Generate the probabilities for the different throws
results = defaultdict(fractions.Fraction)
for throw in itertools.product(range(1,7),repeat=6):
    prob=fractions.Fraction(1,1)
    for die,t in zip(range(1,7),throw):
        prob*=dice[die][t]
    results[sum(throw)]+=prob

#Print results
for r in results:
    print("%2d: %s"%(r,results[r]))
```

Comment: It might be nice to see some explanation of how you arrived at this answer...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, done!  I'm assuming that there won't be a nice elegant way to see this result, so brute force rules the day.  By the way, the code is Python 3.x.